# paypal sandbox account Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm new in the paypal developer environment and I want to test the sandbox feature.

I created a REST API app with two accounts 'buyer' and 'facilitator'

Whene I tried to run the code in samples folder : PayPal Payments - similar to Express Checkout in Classic APIs

[paypal samples](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/)

I had this error:

We're sorry. We can't complete your purchase at this time.
Please return to the merchant and choose another way to pay.
Return to Merchant

[image: paypal sandbox error]

Whene I created another buyer account without a credit card it worked and the error gone but i can't complete the purchase without a credit card.

I'm in algeria but I want that every one can buy from my website is it country limitation ??

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Having the same issue with live account. Sandbox works but app fails in production.